# use trained keras cnn to generate feature maps

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, theano, keras

I trained up a very vanilla CNN using keras/theano that does a pretty good job of detecting whether a small (32X32) portion of an image contains a (relatively simple) object of type A or B (or neither).  The output is an array of three numbers [prob(neither class), prob(A), prob(B)].  Now, I want to take a big image (512X680, methinks) and sweep across the image, running the trained model on each 32X32 sub-image to generate a feature map that's 480X648, at each point consisting of a 3-vector of the aforementioned probabilities.  Basically, I want to use my whole trained CNN as a (nonlinear) filter with three-dimensional output.  At the moment, I am cutting each 32X32 out of the image one at a time and running the model on it, then dropping the resulting 3-vectors in a big 3X480X648 array.  However, this approach is very slow.  Is there a faster/better way to do this?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. It is more about algorithm design. You can refer to paper on R-CNN, fast R-CNN and faster R-CNN series.

Comment: This is actually just what I needed: I wasn't familiar with R-CNN.  I am still wondering, however, if there isn't a way to write a model in Keras (without getting into the weeds too much) where the filters are nonlinear (frozen copies of previously trained CNN).  This might at least make the logic less clunky.